# Why is this running my separate php file when it shouldnt?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have multiple pages for sorting out a table based on certain specification.
I created a page for each table sort but I want it to be on one page.

I have this little snippet of code for when I log onto my dashboard for the first time.

```
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
if(empty($_SESSION['table'])){
    $_SESSION['table'] = "dashboard";
 }
```

I have this jquery function at the bottom.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeString() {
    $.get("changeString.php");
    return false;
}
```

and I have it setup so that when I click on a certain image it will change a string for a conditional and sort it out out accordingly.

Here's my table conditional:

```
 if($_SESSION['table'] == "dashboard"){
      $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT email from loggedin WHERE session_id='$user'");
      $sess=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
      $newValue=$sess['email'];
      $sql2= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM food WHERE OwnerEmail='$newValue'"); 
    }

      elseif($_SESSION['table'] == "Pantry"){

      $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT email from loggedin WHERE session_id='$user'");
      $sess=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
      $newValue=$sess['email'];
       $sql2= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM food WHERE OwnerEmail='$newValue' AND Container='Pantry'");
```

Here's my img link:

```
<a href="#" onClick="changeString()";><img src="iconpantry.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
```

And here's my separate php file called changeString.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['table'] = "Pantry";


?>:
```

Now whats happening is that when I first log in, for some reason it automatically sets $_SESSION['table'] = "Pantry".

Without me even clicking on the image.

Why is this happening?

Comment: i wouldn't use session for things like this... it would be better if you added GET parameters to url , my guess is that you don't reset the session variable , session variables could last for months may have kept "pantry" value from last login session.

Comment: Could you give me a small example of how I would do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user3503344 's answer is correct which fixes your code to reset the session on login , which it didn't do before. but in general if the setting is not going to be consistent (i.e. resets each time user logins) it is better to use get variables.

what if the user has 2 tabs of your site open and wants different setting on each tab ? he can't do that with sessions .

so i say change your table conditional to

```
if(!isset($_GET['table']) || $_GET['table'] == "dashboard"){
  //this happens if ?table=X does not exits or it is set to dashboard
  $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT email from loggedin WHERE session_id='$user'");
  $sess=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
  $newValue=$sess['email'];
  $sql2= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM food WHERE OwnerEmail='$newValue'"); 
}elseif($_GET['table'] == "Pantry"){
  $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT email from loggedin WHERE session_id='$user'");
  $sess=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
  $newValue=$sess['email'];
  $sql2= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM food WHERE OwnerEmail='$newValue' AND Container='Pantry'");
}
```

and for your button you should do something like :

```
<a href="?table=Pantry"><img src="iconpantry.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
```

this way user can also bookmark your site with this preferences so he doesn't have to press button each time if he wants to see Pantry table by default .

Comment: So Im doing something similar to this with the pages for monitoring session ids for users.

I have when I log in it goes to 

       `url.com?id="id"`

But on that page I have another link that links back to it.

    `<a href="url.com">Dashboard</a>`

Now when I try to do something like:

       `<a href="url.com?id=".$_GET['id']."">Dashboard</a>`

It goes to the page but the url says 

        `url.com?id=`

It doest give an id

Comment: `'<a href="url.com/?id='.$_GET['id'].'">'Dashboard</a>` would only have an id if the page that link is on it has an id , e.g. if you put this code on `url.com/` it has no id , but from `url.com/?id=5` it gives you id=5. if in url.com?id=id but still gives you id= (without value) perhaps you have syntax error or a typo

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
if(empty($_SESSION['table'])){
    $_SESSION['table'] = "dashboard";
 }
```

To:

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['table']);
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$_SESSION['table'] = "dashboard";
```

To use GET Method:

URL: url.com/index.php?page=dashboard

PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['page']) && strlen($_GET['page'])>0) {
        if($_GET['page'] == 'dashboard') {
           // Do what you want if the page is dashboard.
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you unset a variable, there is no point checking it with empty() immediately afterwards.

Comment: Well that put it back to normal, but now when I click the image link to change it to Pantry, it redirects back to the dashboard and unsets it again.

Comment: Post the whole PHP source of Pantry. And I've posted the PHP GET Method to do this stuff. @user3486712